# Listen to read only sysfs file using epoll

Tags: linux, epoll

I know that epoll can be used to effectively read on GPIO events from user space, and many other possibilities are possible for sockets. I wanted to listen to sysfs attribute that is read-only with epoll. Is it possible? I always get EPOLLERR here. If anyone could explain what the problem is here, I would appreciate it.

```
mFileFd = open("/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (mFileFd < 0) {
  perror("Error opening file.");
  return -1;
}

mEpollFd = epoll_create(1);
if (mEpollFd < 0) {
  perror("Unable to create epoll");
  return mEpollFd;
}

mEpollEvent.events = EPOLLIN;
mEpollEvent.data.fd = mFileFd;

err = epoll_ctl(mEpollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, mFileFd, & mEpollEvent);
if (err) {
  perror("Unable to add fd to epoll instance.");
  return err;
}

int nfds = 0;
int len = 0;
char buf[200] = {
  0
};

nfds = epoll_wait(mEpollFd, mEpollEvents, 1, -1);
if (nfds < 0) {
  perror("Epoll error 1.");
  return -1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < nfds; i++) {
  if ((mEpollEvents[i].events & EPOLLERR) ||
    (mEpollEvents[i].events & EPOLLHUP)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Epoll error 2.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if (mEpollEvents[i].data.fd == mFileFd) {
    len = read(mFileFd, & buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
    if (len < 0) {
      perror("File read error.");
      return -1;
    }
    buf[len] = '\0';

    printf("Got=%s", buf);
  }

}
```

Comment: `epoll` does not read. `read()` reads.

Comment: What I mean is to listen to the file changes, obviously.

Comment: Then could be this functionality is not implemented inside the driver. Find your thermal driver source code in kernel and see how it's implemented and if it does support poll call.

Comment: @KamilCuk Hmm that does help a lot actually. I will do that.

Comment: @KamilCuk It seems there is no epoll tied to file_operations. Do you have any idea how a sysfs file could be listened to in another way?

Comment: sysfs is a direct view of kernel structures. There are no files to have events.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that polling on thermal devices are recently implemented on May 2020: https://lwn.net/Articles/819433/